# How to fix a TDS Hedgehog deploy error: 'Exception The given key was not present in the dictionary.'?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sitecore8.2, tds

The TDS projects in my Visual Studio 2017 solution are all of a sudden not syncing to Sitecore. 
I've confirmed that the Sitecore instance will still open and function properly in the browser. 
The Access Guid in the TDS Project properties and in the _DEV/web.config file match. 
When I run a "Test", it always fails at the "Verify Access guid is correct" step.

The error message in the TDS Output screen is as follows:

Inner Exception Details:
Exception The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (WebException):
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
Connection Test Failure: Failed to complete test.
Exception The given key was not present in the dictionary. (KeyNotFoundException):
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.CallServiceWrapper[T](TdsServiceSoapClient client, SitecoreProjectNode project, Func`2 clientCall)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ProjectTests.AccessGuidTest.Execute()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.BuildTestDialog.RunTests()

Can anyone help with this error?

This is on Visual Studio 2017, Sitecore 8.2, and TDS Hedgehog version 5.7.0.16

I've already tried restarting VS, deleting the contents of the _DEV folder and reinstalling the Sitecore connector, and verified that the Hedgehog dlls in the "wwwroot/website_name/Website/bin" folder are the correct version of TDS.

[Failed Tds test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqkfk.png)

[Tds error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yssmb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was resolved. I updated from version 5.7.0.16 to 5.8. Hedgehog support said the issue was a redirect handler error caused by custom error handlers